# Create functions in matlab

Tags: arrays, function, matlab, loops, for-loop

How can I create a function with MATLAB so I can call it any where in my code?

I'm new to MATLAB so I will write a PHP example of the code I want to write in MATLAB!

```
    Function newmatlab(n){
    n=n+1;
    return n;
    }
array=array('1','2','3','4');
foreach($array as $x){
$result[]=newmatlab($x);
}
print_f($result);
```

So in nutshell, I need to loop an array and apply a function to each item in this array.

Can some one show me the above function written in MATLAB so I can understand better?

Note: I need this because I wrote a code that analyzes a video file and then plots data on a graph. I then and save this graph into Excel and jpg. My problem is that I have more than 200 video to analyze, so I need to automate this code to loop inside folders and analyze each *.avi file inside and etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a very basic question, which you could easily answer by reading the comprehensive [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/). I suggest you look there first and come back if you need more specific help.

Comment: i did read that before, but coundn't understand ! thats why i ask, is there a way to include the function in my file ? or i must create it on different file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, the documentation covers this pretty thoroughly, but perhaps we can help you understand.

There are a handful of ways that you can define functions in Matlab, but probably the most useful for you to get started is to define one in an m-file.  I'll use your example code.  You can do this by creating a file called `newmatlab.m` in your project's directory that looks something like this

```
% newmatlab.m
function result = newmatlab(array)
result = array + 1
```

Note that the function has the same name as the file and that there is no explicit `return` statement - it figures that out by what you've named the output parameter(s) (`result` in this case).

Then, in the same directory, you can create a script (or another function) that calls your `newmatlab` function by that name:

```
% main.m (or whatever)
a = [1 2 3 4];
b = newmatlab(a)
```

That's it!  This is a simplified explanation, but hopefully enough to get you started and then the documentation can help more.

PS: There's no "include" in Matlab; any functions that are defined in m-files in the current  `path` are visible.  You can find out what's in the path by using the `path` command.  Roughly, it's going to consist of

1. Matlab's own directory
2. The MATLAB subdirectory of your Documents directory
3. The current working directory

Comment: Thank you very much :), now i get it. it just didn't make sense to me where should i put this function file and how can i include it and how can i control return, thank you very much for your amazing answer :)